# function not changing result based on arguments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Imports System.Web.Security

Public Class Form1
    Dim symbols As Integer = 0

    Private Sub cbSymbols_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbSymbols.CheckedChanged
        If cbSymbols.CheckState = 1 Then
            symbols = 1
        ElseIf cbSymbols.CheckState = 0 Then
            symbols = 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
        Dim password As String = Membership.GeneratePassword(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 6, symbols)
        Label1.Text = password
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Font = New Font("Arial", 14)
        If ComboBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0    ' The first item has index 0 '
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, no matter if my checkbox (cbSymbols) is checked, my passwords have 1 symbol while ticked, and 2 symbols unticked. Can anybody help me diagnose this problem and/or improve my code? Thanks.

Comment: Have ypou set a breakpoint int `btn_Generate_Click` to see if the value of `symbols` is correct?

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx) the second parameter only specifies the *minimum* number of symbols. Are you expecting it to impose a *maximum* instead?

Comment: @RogerRowland Indeed I was, any idea how to do this?

Comment: No idea - I expect you'll have to write your own function, I don't know of any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx)

```
Public Shared Function GeneratePassword ( _
    length As Integer, _
    numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters As Integer _
) As String
```

numberOfNonAlphanumericCharactersType: The **minimum** number of non-alphanumeric characters (such as @, #, !, %, &, and so on) in the generated password.

This explains why you got those results.
I've ran the test a few times myself and I even got a passwords with only symbols.

**UPDATE**

Setting a maximum of special characters is not out-of-the-box available.

There are a few options to roll out your own:

1. Start from the password generated by `MemberShip.GeneratePassword`,
   search the password-string for special symbols
   (`!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)`) and when you have reached your counter
   replace it with a random letter or digit.
2. Start from scratch and create your own password generator.
3. ...

Comment: Ah so it was, that's what I get for late night programming. Any idea how to impose a maximum number of symbols?

Comment: Updated my answer. Sadly there's nothing available out-of-the-box in the .Net framework (afaik). And I totally understand the thing  about late night programming. ;-)